# Calling a function only once despite the script itself being compiled and executed multiple times

Tags: python

I have a python script where I am initializing a set of data structures(persistent dictionaries to be specific) I compile the python script multiple times but want to call that function only the first time. Flags do not help my case because I want it to be persistent. I am new to this. Any help in this direction would be great.

Flags do not work in my case or rather they do not serve my purpose

```
def init():
    #initialize the shelve module to store some keys and values
    #close the dictionary
```

init should be called only once despite the script being rerun many times

Comment: You should considering using a database, perhaps `sqlite`? Research about it.

Comment: Can you provide an example of your code? That might make it easier for us to figure out solutions that fit your use case.

Comment: One semi-permanent solution would be to keep a flag *in a file*, or in an environment variable, or in some other thing that doesn't reset when you rerun the script.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. But why is that semi-permanent

Comment: Indeed, provide a minimal working code example which reproduces the problem. Also, what do you mean by "compiling" a python script?

Comment: An environment variable isn't going to work because you can't affect the outer environment from inside a program.  The program is running in a shell containing the environment you might affect, and it is going to go away.  environment variables are for passing data in to code, not the other way around.

Comment: "Persistent" means to store something such that it will survive over time.  How persistent something is is a big topic in computer science.  But for your purposes, it probably means something stored on your hard drive.  So what is it that you are doing that is persistent, and therefore needs to not be done a second time?  What are "persistent dictionaries"?  Where are these "stored"?

Comment: I am trying to use the shelve module in python to store some information with keys. I want it to be persistent forever so that it can be accessed anytime I call the script to read it and access it in different functions